# Match multiple first names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I would like to find a RegEx that allows matching (SQL join) without taking into consideration the order or full string... as following:

> ```
> Case 1
> Left: Mr. John Doe
> Right: Doe John
> Result: match
>
> Case 2
> Left: John Doe
> Right Doe
> Result: match
>
> Case 3
> Left: Robert-John Doe
> Right: Robert Doe
> Result: match
> ```
>
> etc...

Is this possible? I will add this in the join condition of two tables in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Rather not... You better normalize your data, then it's a (series of) simple `=` operations.

Comment: Not sure how you see normalization... but even with it (which is what I currently do by using "nls_sort = binary_ai") the problem stays the same - I still need to split every word using some kind of regexp_substr, to connect, to sort then to pack again in a string by, probably, using listagg(). The volume of data is pretty big (10+M) and it will run forever.

Comment: "Not sure how you see normalization..." -- one column for the salutation one for the title, one for the (full) given name (or a defined part of it, e.g. just the first one) one for the surname, etc., not all in one string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` and `regexp_count` together as :

```
with t( id, col1, col2 ) as
(
 select 1, 'Mr. John Doe'   , 'Doe John'   from dual union all
 select 2, 'John Doe'       , 'Doe'        from dual union all
 select 3, 'Robert-John Doe', 'Robert Do'  from dual        
), t2 as
(
select distinct t.*, 
       regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as col01, 
       regexp_substr(col2, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as col02,
       level                
  from dual 
 cross join t
connect by level <= greatest(regexp_count(col1, '[^ ]+'),regexp_count(col2, '[^ ]+'))  
 order by id, level
 )
select distinct id, col1, col2, 'matched' as status
  from t2 t
 where exists ( select 1 from t2 where id = t.id and ( col01 = t.col02 or col02 = t.col01 ) )
 union all
select distinct id, col1, col2, 'Not matched'
  from t2 t
 where not exists ( select 1 from t2 where id = t.id and ( col01 = t.col02 or col02 = t.col01 ) )
 order by id;

ID  COL1            COL2        STATUS
--  --------------- ----------  -----------
1   Mr. John Doe    Doe John    matched
2   John Doe        Doe         matched
3   Robert-John Doe Robert Do   Not matched
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/DESO62533)</kbd>

*P.S. I changed row three slightly.*